# how do I autoconvert a struct* to a dict?

Tags: cython

#### mystruct.pxd

```
ctypedef struct foo:
    pass

ctypedef struct myStruct:
    int field1
    int field2
    foo* field3
```

#### mystruct.pyx

```
class MyStruct:
    cdef myStruct* _ptr
    def __cinit__(self):
        self._ptr = create_myStruct()
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        if key in self._ptr[0]:
            return self._ptr[0][key]
```

`__getattr__` does not compile with cython. *Attempting to index non-array type 'myStruct'*
Removing the `[0]` results in a compiler crash.

Attempts to do:

```
def get_dict(self):
    return self._ptr      # cannot convert 'myStruct *' to Python object
    return self._ptr[0]   # cannot convert 'myStruct' to Python object
```

These structs have many fields that I need to access as properties. Writing basic @property wrappers is adding a lot of clutter to the file so I'd like to be able to use a simple **getaddr** instead. Any thought?

UPDATE: changed type of field3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem is with `foo* field3` since foo is a custom struct and not a primitive type (numeric, char*) autoconversion will not work. There does not appear to be a way to fix this directly. I have two workarounds:

1. Change the type of field3 to `unsigned int` (or whatever your pointer size is) and cast to `foo*` when you need to access the sub-structure. This is not a very nice workaround but if your members are really opaque types and not accessible structs, it works just fine.
2. Write something to explicitly convert to a dict.

This is what I ended up doing. It's another repetition of the field names but it can be easily created with copy-paste-modify

```
def to_dict(self):
  return {'field1':self._ptr.field1,
          'field2':self._ptr.field2,
          'field3':FooWrapper().from_ptr(self._ptr.field3)  # or an int if opaque
         }
cdef class FooWrapper:
    cdef foo* _ptr
    def from_ptr(self, ptr):
        assert(ptr is not NULL)
        self._ptr = ptr
        return self
```